# Can you live stream WebM to Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, vlc-media-player

I know you can stream media by using stuff like VLC to browser that also with a VLC plugin.
Chrome also supports WebM (VP8) encoding video format playback natively.

BUT when I try to stream a WebM VP8 encoded file to chrome (with VLC) in a  tag, chrome starts to download it, had control of the player just become dummy buttons.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same issue...

Comment: How are you streaming WebM with VLC?

Comment: The code you wrote to stream files please.